# Migration of Custom Workflows from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, workflow

I have never worked on Custom Workflows and for now I need to migrate a Custom Workflow solution from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010. I have converted the solution in VS2010 and it if error free.

Will simply building and deploying the Workflow solution do the task or I need to create a new solution and write the code again?

Answer (score 0):

Workflows should continue to work fine. You should test your migration on a dev/QA server before migerating to production. Only potential issue is in a database attach upgrade when you [Prepare the new environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026.aspx#Create):

If you had disabled the Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job in your Office SharePoint Server 2007 environment, make sure that you disable this timer job in your new environment also. If this timer job is enabled in the new environment and disabled in the previous version environment, you might lose workflow associations when you upgrade. For more information about this timer job, see [Disable preservation of workflow history (SharePoint Server 2010).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522.aspx)

Also check:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/01/15/migrating-a-2007-workflow-to-visual-studio-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ba9c0baa-7fde-4880-a67e-edbd262b5ee3/upgrading-custom-workflows-after-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: I have read exact answer somewhere else as well.

Comment: You might have hundred of answers. But i would suggest you to test first on your dev\QA environment before migrationg to production.